# Python script Same seed combination doesn't derive same address

Tags: python, hd-wallets, bip39

This script runs great but for some reason, it doesn't derive the same results as iancoleman.io m/44'/60'/0'/0/0 with the same seed words combination..can anyone spot it?

```
import itertools
import hashlib
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
from bip32utils import BIP32Key
from mnemonic import Mnemonic
import random
import eth_keys
from eth_utils import keccak, to_checksum_address

words = ['pair', 'decade', 'amount', 'two', 'bless', 'season', 'soap', 'ribbon', 'second', 'element', 'melody', 'science', 'fatal', 'october', 'else', 'segment', 'match', 'circle', 'poet', 'silk', 'absorb', 'manage', 'tent', 'gas']
target_address = "0xa7a98dB3cBC29c6AB1c2c73C4900F09318927115"
wordlist = Mnemonic("english").wordlist
ETH_DERIVATION_PATH = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/0"

while True:
    subset = random.sample(words, 24)
    seed_phrase = ' '.join(subset)
    if Mnemonic("english").check(seed_phrase) == True:
        seed_bytes = pbkdf2_hmac("sha512", seed_phrase.encode('utf-8'), b"mnemonic", 2048)
        print("Trying:", seed_phrase)
        master_key = BIP32Key.fromEntropy(seed_bytes)
        private_key_bytes = master_key.ChildKey(
            44 + 2**31
        ).ChildKey(
            60 + 2**31
        ).ChildKey(
            0 + 2**31
        ).ChildKey(0).ChildKey(0).PrivateKey().hex()
        public_key_bytes = eth_keys.keys.PrivateKey(bytes.fromhex(private_key_bytes)).public_key
        address = to_checksum_address(keccak(public_key_bytes[1:]).hex()[24:])
        if address == target_address:
            print("Seed phrase:", seed_phrase)
            print("Address:", target_address)
            print("Target address reached!")
            exit()
        else:
            print("Address:", address)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's in the checksum, public key > public address conversion..note to selfL read up on eth_utils documentation. 48 hrs awake..

`code`public_key_bytes = eth_keys.keys.PrivateKey(bytes.fromhex(private_key_bytes)).public_key
        address = to_checksum_address(keccak(public_key_bytes[1:]).hex()[24:])`code`